# Laravel retrieve values from foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have these models with their related db tables,at the moment I can retrieve all the requirement

```
Requirement::all()
```

but I just have a list of foreigns key (destination_id,applier_id,doc_id). How can i retrieve directly the row connected to that foreigns key?

```
class Requirement extends Model
  {
    protected $fillable = [
        'required',
        'destination_id',
        'applier_id',
        'doc_id'
    ];

  public function destination()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Destination::class);
  }

  public function applier()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(Applier::class);
  }

  public function doc()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(Doc::class);
  }
}



class Doc extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'description',
        'note'
  ];

    public function requirements()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Requirement::class);
    }
 }



class Destination extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'country',
        'passying_country',
        'transfer_conditions',
        'passing_conditions'
     ];

   public function requirements()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Requirement::class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `with()` function instead of `all()`. So if you try this following :

```
$requirements =  Requirement::with('destination', 'applier', 'doc')->get();
```

Make it `dd($requirements)` and look the output.

Hope it will work.

Comment: Very good solution. It returns what I want but also the the list of foreign key it self, I am tring to avoid that with pluck() but doesn't work

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful for you please make it trick as an answer. Thank you.